# how to load a java class along with static initializations before they are used?

Tags: java, static, initialization

I need to load some classes along with *their respective static initializations*, for example, in a factory method implementation.

If I just make reference to the class using the below syntax, the JVM does not run the static initialization part. Actually, does the JVM even load the classes?

`Class<Shape> shapeClass = Shape.class;`
or
`Shape s = null;`

But with class.forname() it does execute static initializations. 
`Class.forname("Shape");`
The question is if this is the only way to do load a java class along with static initializations? Or are there other ways? Any significant performance penalties for using class.forname()?

Comment: +1 I just came across a similar problem, and I'd also like to find out whether or not static initializers have already run on an instance of `Class<?>`.

Answer (score 3):

From Class.forName(String className) API: *Invoking this method is equivalent to: Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)*.

The second argument = true means initialize class, and initialize class means run static initializers

This is a test to check

```
package test;

class Test2 {
    static {
        System.out.println("static init");
    }
}

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("test.Test2");
    }
}
```

output

```
static init
```

but if you load Test2 with

```
Class.forName("test.Test2", false, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

there will be no output. You can also use this test to see that `Test.class.getName()` does not load the class either.

The simplest way to make it load is to add an empty static method and call it:

```
class Test2 {
     public static void load() {
     }
     ...
Test2.load();
```

Comment: the question was regarding alternatives for class.forname() syntax.

Answer (score 1):

When you load/resolve a class, the static initializers are executed in the order they are defined. It shouldn't matter *how* you load them, reflection or not. That is, unless you're meaning some other sort of initialization?